# How do I localize routes with next.js and next-i18next?

Tags: next.js, i18next

I need to change the name of the route when I change the language. For example, I have a route `/en/career` but when I change to Czech language, I need a route `/cs/kariera`. Basically I need the URLs to be localized. Right now, when I'm on `/en/career` and change language to cs, I get `/cs/career`. This page should not exist at all and when I render the page on server, I correctly get 404. Can I do something like this with next-i18next package? If so, how?

I found this package https://github.com/vonschau/next-routes-with-locale which probably does exactly what I need but it's apparently no longer maintained and doesn't work under next.js 8.

Comment: I think this depends heavily on how you define and manage your routes. E.g. are they dynamic, are they defined in a CMS, are they hardcoded etc. Ultimately, if you want a link to an alternative language version of the current page, you'll need to pass all the route name variations to every page.

Answer (score 8):

What I did eventually was to use `next-routes` package and defined specific route for every page, such as:

```
module.exports = routes()
    .add('en-career-listing', '/en/career/:listing', 'career/listing')
    .add('cs-career-listing', '/cs/kariera/:listing', 'career/listing')
    .add('en-career', '/en/career', 'career')
    .add('cs-career', '/cs/kariera', 'career')
    .add('en-our-story', '/en/our-story', 'our-story')
    .add('cs-our-story', '/cs/nas-pribeh', 'our-story')
```

And I also had to create a custom `Link` component based on `next/link` where I manually added the language to URL.

Comment: This is a good solution, you can combine the i18next Link with the next-routes one, by passing the first as an argument to the constructor https://github.com/fridays/next-routes/blob/master/src/index.js#L11-L12

Comment: Can you share your solution? Thanks

Comment: my requirements are same, can you please share your full solution? Thanks in advance.

Comment: @SalmanLone What exactly are you missing? This is the full solution. There's really not anything else other than described.

Comment: I have actually implemented these routes. The thing is, when i am trying to push the route value like Router.pushRoute("route_name"); it works for couple of times and then does not change the url. can you tell us how you used these routes in <Link> or Router in your functional components? Thanks for the help in advance @samuelg0rd0n

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions. However, I would like to ask, which translation package you are using ? i tried to use the next-i18n with subpath as a language indicator. however I just canot get the connection point between the URL with the language you are passing with the next i18n subpath ?
are you using subpath or query for the language ?
and can you provide an example on how did you call a route from a server side and on client side.

Comment: @SalmanLone did you manage to do it? I am using @lingui/react and the same as above answer. But routes does not work :(

Answer (score 0):

next-i18next supports this [functionality](https://github.com/isaachinman/next-i18next#5-locale-subpaths), it called locale subpaths.

You need to configure: `new NextI18Next({ localeSubpaths: 'foreign' })`, and then use the Link & Router that `NextI18Next` instance has on it, not the **next/router**.

Comment: I'm sorry but this is not what I need. I used localeSubpaths options but it does exactly what I want to avoid and what I describe in the question - for example, if I'm on /en/career and I switch to cs, I get /cs/career. But I need /cs/kariera - to change the rest of the URL too.

Comment: `localeSubpaths: 'foreign'` is deprecated now.

Answer (score 0):

Solution for **nextjs 13** and app router is to use next **rewrites** with next-intl.

Resources:

- **next-itnl localizing pathnames** - https://next-intl-docs.vercel.app/docs/routing/middleware#localizing-pathnames
- **next.js rewrites** - https://nextjs.org/docs/pages/api-reference/next-config-js/rewrites
- n**ext.js 13 named routes example** - https://github.com/amannn/next-intl/tree/feat/next-13-rsc/examples/example-next-13-named-routes

(in: next.config.js):

```
 rewrites() {
    return [
      {
        source: '/cs/kariera',
        destination: '/en/career',
      },
    ]
  },
```

**File structure: /app/[lang]/career/page.tsx**

You want to map url to directory:

- /cs/kariera -> /cs/career
- /en/career -> /en/career

Myo riginal answer: Details: [Translating URLs in Next.js 13 with App directory and next-intl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76219701/translating-urls-in-next-js-13-with-app-directory-and-next-intl/76874385#76874385)