# NextJS i18next Nextjs Localize Routes

Tags: next.js, i18next

I've fully implemented next-i18next for my NextJS website. Everything is working as it should be:

- Automatically detects language using i18next middleware
- Changes language with language select button
- Translations with only loading in relevant namespaces etc etc

However, I would like to localise the route names so that they reflect the set language.

I understand how this can be done using next-routes and this exchange was particularly useful:

[How do I localize routes with next.js and next-i18next?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56426126/how-do-i-localize-routes-with-next-js-and-next-i18next)

In that example, routes are set up like:

```
routes.add('en-home', '/', 'index')
routes.add('de-home', '/de', 'index')
routes.add('en-test', '/test', 'test')
routes.add('de-test', '/de/prufung', 'test')
```

I tried to implement Route and Link from next-routes using the following pattern as an example:

1. Get current language from `i18n.language`
2. Set link url according to language set

```
<Link route={`${lang}-home`}></Link>
```

And again, using a similar pattern for next-routes Router such as:

```
Router.pushRoute(`${lang}-home`)
```

However, this is not working.

I noticed in the referenced thread that @samuelg0rd0n commented that he created a custom Link component.

Please can anybody guide me how to change all the routes according to which language the website is set to?

Thanks!

Comment: Hi Paul, welcome to StackOverflow! I just sent a dedicated example for you. I hope it can help.

Comment: @FrancisRodrigues can you please send me the same example? i am facing the same issue and need to implement custom link with can work with routes.js and also i18ln.js

Comment: Have you found any solution? Could you please share it? Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I strongly recommend you trying an official Next.js example:

### Next.js -- Named routes example (next-routes)

https://github.com/zeit/next.js/tree/canary/examples/with-next-routes

But I'm seen that it needs an additional server and also will fail if we custom our app structure as my own project example:

```
| src/app
   | -- pages
       | -- post.js
       | -- category.js
   | -- server.js (for routes)

| src/functions
   | -- index.js (lambda function for server-side)
```

And if I run `next src/app` it will fail with the following error:

```sh
Error: > Couldn't find a `pages` directory. Please create one under the project root
    at findPagesDir (/home/paneladm/projects/paneladm-dev/travel-website/node_modules/next/dist/lib/find-pages-dir.js:3:170)
    at new DevServer (/home/paneladm/projects/paneladm-dev/travel-website/node_modules/next/dist/server/next-dev-server.js:1:3491)
    at createServer (/home/paneladm/projects/paneladm-dev/travel-website/node_modules/next/dist/server/next.js:2:105)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/paneladm/projects/paneladm-dev/travel-website/src/app/server.js:14:13)
    at Module._compile (module.js:653:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:664:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:566:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:506:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:498:3)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:694:10)
```

### Next.js team is working in a simple solution now

> This adds an example showing how to remove the need for a custom server for an existing application using next-routes by leveraging the new custom routes support built-in to Next.js

You should update `next` to `9.1.+` and implement your own routes as following:

```js
const nextRoutes = require('next-routes');
const routes = (module.exports = nextRoutes());

routes.add('category', '/category/:slug');
routes.add('post', '/post/:lang/:slug');
```

In your `next.config.js` file, enable `experimental` property and implement `rewrites` method as below:

```
const { routes } = require('./routes');

...

experimental: {
    rewrites() {
      const rewrites = [];

      for (const route of routes) {
        if (route.pattern !== route.page) {
          rewrites.push({
            source: route.pattern,
            destination: route.page,
          });
        }
      }

      return rewrites;
    }
  },
```

Now your structure should be:

```
| src/app
   | -- pages
       | -- post.js
       | -- category.js
```

But if you want to custom your pages, try change the routes like this:

```js
...

routes.add('category/[slug]', '/category/:slug');
routes.add('post/[slug]', '/post/:lang/:slug');
```

It will point to `pages --> category --> [slug].js` file instead.

See more details in the new [PR implementation](https://github.com/zeit/next.js/tree/ab227440716d21c2f205eaaec0d943b778587e98/examples/next-routes) files.

References

- [Next.js PR 9519 - Add next-routes/custom-routes example](https://github.com/zeit/next.js/pull/9519)