# Translating URLs in Next.js 13 with App directory and next-intl

Tags: next.js, internationalization, i18next, react-i18next

I'm currently working on a multilingual Next.js 13 application, and I'm using the next-intl package for internationalization. I've been trying to set up translated URLs for my routes, but I'm running into some issues.

Here's an example of what I want to achieve. If the source language is Danish, a route could be:mypage/om.
For English, it would be: mypage/en/about.

My project is structured to utilize the App directory (/app/[lang]/page.tsx).

I've followed the next-intl documentation to set up internationalized routing, but I'm having difficulty getting the URL translation to work correctly with this setup.

I need the pages to be able to take advantage of "generateStaticParams" so we can build static pages with all the diffrent languages and allow each url to be language specific but still only have to create 1 single page for the main language. I hope this makes sense.

When I navigate to mypage/om, the application correctly resolves to the Danish version, i can also see the english version on mypage/en/om. However,  I want to be able to navigate to  mypage/en/about, without having to make multiple pages with diffrent names.

Does anyone have experience setting up translated URLs with next-intl in Next.js 13, particularly with an App directory structure? Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Let me start by saying that nextjs is not a good framework to work with multilingual websites that require url translation. This is simply non existant in their offering and it is a major setback to any non English development (as they often require the country's main language as well as the current *lingua franca*).

---

Regarding your issue, I'm unsure if it is / will be possible to do this with next-intl but I'm sharing a possible solution to the issue of url translation.

The solution I've come up with is offered by a library called "next-roots", which generates all the paths at build time as well as their equivalent in the target languages.

It uses a root folder in which you insert your whole application.
For instance, given your example:

```
// defaultRoot folder is a sibling of the /app folder
defaultRoot/
  om/
    layout.tsx
    page.tsx
    i18n.mjs
```

In that i18n.mjs, you specify the languages and the url translation for that language. For instance:

```
   // i18n.mjs 
   export const routeNames = [{ locale: 'en', path: 'about-us' }];
```

They also support dynamic routing.

If you're interested, here's the source: https://github.com/svobik7/next-roots

---

Edit:
I take it back, after dwelving a bit, it is possible:
https://next-intl-docs.vercel.app/docs/routing/navigation#localized-pathnames

Answer (score -1):

This is something we are also waiting for / have the same issue, and the solution for it is cooking...

Check the [Next-Intl Roadmap](https://next-intl-docs.vercel.app/docs/next-13/server-components#roadmap)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -2):

UPDATE:
Now this is possible by next intl 3.X.X. Check docs: https://next-intl-docs.vercel.app/

You should use next.js **rewrites**.

Resources:

- **next-itnl localizing pathnames** - https://next-intl-docs.vercel.app/docs/routing/middleware#localizing-pathnames
- **next.js rewrites** https://nextjs.org/docs/pages/api-reference/next-config-js/rewrites
- **next.js 13 named routes example** -https://github.com/amannn/next-intl/tree/feat/next-13-rsc/examples/example-next-13-named-routes

Your example:

(in: next.config.js):

```
 rewrites() {
    return [
      {
        source: '/da/om',
        destination: '/da/about',
      },
    ]
  },
```

File structure: **/app/[lang]/about/page.tsx**

You want to map url to directory:

- /da/om -> /da/about
- /en/about -> /en/about